# Multiple database in single query is possible?

Tags: php, database

[PHP] How can I query a data from two database in one statement?

Please give me the easy way. and How to connect 2 database to use it?

Thank you

Comment: What are you talking about? Are you using MySQL? What data do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use database tables from different databases in one query, *if* your current connection is allowed to access both databases.

You just need to prefix every table name with the database name:

```
SELECT * FROM `databasename`.`tablename` ...  
... LEFT JOIN `databasename_2`.`tablename`....
```

Comment: Not every table even. Just those tables that are not in currently selected database ;)

Comment: How can I take connection to allow access both database? Give me an example

Comment: @Giffary: this depends on what privileges have been set up on MySQL server for the user you're connecting as.

Comment: Since this isn't possible unless "your current connection is allowed to access both databases", it would be nice if you could tell us **how** to ensure that is the case! I came here looking for a quick and easy-to-implement solution; I would rather not spend hours scouring the MySQL docs if it could be easily avoided.

Answer (score 3):

A 'database' in MySQL terms is a logical unit within a database server. To query tables from two separate databases, see Pekka's answer (though pleas note that restrictions apply - some JOINS might not work as intended etc. For more info see the MySQL docs.)

If you want to query two different database *servers* within the same statement, then the answer is that that isn't possible. You will have to create two separate connections, and query each of them individually.